# Need inputs for logic for Codebehind in Infopath Button

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have an infopath form,when i click on the button it should redirect to sharepoint list item's add item template.. in the code behined i gave

```
 try
 {
  string url = "Sharepoint List item's URL";
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("url");
  }
  catch
  {
  }
```

But i am getting Security error like this

System.Security.SecurityException
Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
   at Activity_Profile.FormCode.btnNewReportingUnit_Clicked(Object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Office.InfoPath.Internal.ButtonEventHost.OnButtonClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust._ButtonEventSink_SinkHelper.OnClick(DocActionEvent pEvent)

Please help me on this :)

Comment: even in the URL Field if i gave www.google.com i am getting the same error....Problem with using HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("url");

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Try using `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("url", false);`
- Make sure you reference `System.Web` and add an imports statement for it
- Check that your form security is set to **Full trust**

I'm thinking this has to do with the form not having full trust and hence not being allowed to redirect anywhere.

Comment: Moontear i am getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object at HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("url", false);I have added System.Web and Security as Full Trust

Comment: Does it make a difference when you use a variable instead of *"url"*? Like myVar.toString()?

Comment: Any way i sortout the problem using some hidden text box...Thanks for your support :)