# Error while navigating the page to another page

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am trying to redirect page on Button click of infopath form using the below code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", true);
```

But i am getting this error:

**"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

Answer (score 1):

Does it help you ?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com", false);
```

Take a look here,

http://mfawazsp.blogspot.in/2010/02/problem-with-responseredirect-in.html

or/and this,

[Need inputs for logic for Codebehind in Infopath Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467721/need-inputs-for-logic-for-codebehind-in-infopath-button)

or/and this,

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/sharepoint2010programming/thread/16c7f7c5-545e-4375-b093-91da23041624

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("anyurl", false);

Comment: I've shared some links with really nice solutions, do look at them :)